# How to import db:schema diff into the database in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, data-migration

i know that is should use migrations, just asking. it would be useful/beautiful to be able work on local mysql database adding fields, indexes etc. 
and then

- schema dump
- git push heroku ...
- heroku db:schema:diff:apply <- !!! without loosing remote data

i know

- can't haddle table/fields rename case
- this is bat babbit

i really like to use great db managers like SQLyog, why can't I? I can't if i hawe to write every change in migration file by hand.

is this possible? is there similar plugin?

ps: i know about [this](http://errtheblog.com/posts/65-automatically) beauty:

this is exactly what I'm looking for. Problem is that it is for old rails, and not suported anymore

thx

Comment: ups found this: https://github.com/pjhyett/auto_migrations

Answer (score 0):

[**this**](https://github.com/pjhyett/auto_migrations) is it! by author words dynamite!

handles

- filed size changes
- filed create/drop
- create/drop indices

pached to work with schema-auto.rb and not schema.rb

great!